# "Executing an update/delete query" exception for @NamedQuery doing REMOVE

Tags: sql, exception, sql-update, persistence

The following exception thrown for Spring Batch application:

```
19:12:40,083 ERROR main AbstractStep:213 - Encountered an error executing the step
javax.persistence.TransactionRequiredException: Executing an update/delete query
```

Code,where named query used:

```
entityManagerFactory.createEntityManager()
                    .createNamedQuery("removeQuery").executeUpdate();
```

also tried to wrap this code in *begin* and *commit* methods of *EntityTransaction* object and, didn't help:

```
EntityManager em = entityManagerFactory.createEntityManager();
EntityTransaction transaction = em.getTransaction();
transaction.begin();
entityManagerFactory.createEntityManager()
                    .createNamedQuery("removeQuery").executeUpdate();
transaction.commit();
em.close();
entityManagerFactory.close();
```

thank you in advance

Comment: And what does `removeQuery` looks like?

Answer (score 2):

You don't use same entity manager to create your transaction and to create your query.

Replace

```
entityManagerFactory.createEntityManager()
                    .createNamedQuery("removeQuery").executeUpdate();
```

by

```
em.createNamedQuery("removeQuery").executeUpdate();
```